# Wagtail custom settings not showing

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I created a new project using python 3.6 by following the link tutorial:
http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/index.html.

Then I tried to create a custom configuration following the link tutorial: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html?highlight=Settings

However, the link in settings never appears.

Any tips on what it might be?

**[UPDATE]**

Github project: https://github.com/eduardocp/wagtail/

Comment: Have you definitely added 'wagtail.contrib.settings' to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and restarted the server?

Comment: Yes, I followed the whole tutorial and nothing =(

Comment: OK, could you please include the relevant section of your `settings.py` and the `models.py` that includes your `SocialMediaSettings` class?

Comment: There is nothing different from the tutorial, it's exactly how it's there, it's a completely new project with only a new file called `settingsmodel.py` with the contents of the tutorial's `SocialMediaSettings` class.

Comment: I tried put the content of `SocialMediaSettings` into models.py, but had no effect too

Comment: Can you share the whole project, e.g. on Github?

Comment: I updated with the link project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your `SocialMediaSettings` class to your `models.py` file, not create a new file.

This `models.py` file needs to be the one in the `home` folder.